# What are Accept verbs in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, acceptverbs

While referring asp.net mvc I got stuck on Accept verbs. I know Accept verbs are used for polymorphism in mvc but how do they work ? I think there are 7 Accept verbs in mvc:

1. `HttpVerbs.Get`
2. `HttpVerbs.Post`
3. `HttpVerbs.Put`
4. `HttpVerbs.Delete`
5. `HttpVerbs.Head`
6. `HttpVerbs.Patch`
7. `HttpVerbs.Options`

what do they mean and how do they help to make polymorphism in asp.net mvc please help and what are their short hands ( example: [httppost] and [httpget] i knows)

Comment: These are Enumerations for [HTTP Protocol verbs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Answer (score 3):

> **Delete**: Requests that a specified URI be deleted.
>
> **Get**: Retrieves the information or entity that is identified by the URI of the request.
>
> **Head**: Retrieves the message headers for the information or entity that is       identified by the URI of the request.
>
> **Options**: Represents a request for information about the communication options available on the request/response chain
>   identified by the Request-URI.
>
> **Patch**: Requests that a set of changes described in the request entity be applied to the resource identified by the Request- URI.
>
> **Post**: Posts a new entity as an addition to a URI.
>
> **Put**: Replaces an entity that is identified by a URI.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpverbs(v=vs.118).aspx)

Also you can use `[AcceptVerbs]` to accept other verbs that are not part of the HttpVerbs enum - eg. `[AcceptVerbs("Trace")]`

Update: actually attributes are examples of [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) used within the .NET framework. So those attributes are some built-in implementations that handles HTTP stuff for you so you don’t have to put those code in all of your controller action methods.

[Aspect-oriented Programming and Code Contracts in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/aspect-oriented-programming-and-code-contracts-in-asp.net-mvc/)

[Aspect Oriented Programming in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244400/aspect-oriented-programming-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: You omitted the link to the [MSDN AcceptVerbs documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpverbs(v=vs.118).aspx), which pretty much covers it. Why people don't look at the documentation before coming here is beyond me.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Thanks, I've added the source.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi thz for your answer but yet i dont understand the core  concept  about how this attributes help for polymorphism by putting  the attributes in front of the action in controller

Comment: @Aakashp maybe you could post that as a question and we could all learn - if you do feel free to mention me in comment with link